# How to copy gridview content to a data table on postback

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

My project has a GridView to display some information. That GridView has some OnRowDataBound processing to massage the data. What I'm trying to do is copy the resulting GridView into a DataTable so I can generate a CSV file. The CSV is generated when the user clicks a button. So the GridView is on the screen and populated and a PostBack occurs. The GridView is not being re-bound on PostBack. What is the recommended way to do this? Here is the code I'm trying currently but I just end up with the headings and blank rows. Debugging confirms that row.Cells[i].Text is empty even though the heading is correct and there is the same number of rows as my GridView contained.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("export");

foreach (DataControlField column in myGV.Columns)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = column.HeaderText });
}

foreach (GridViewRow row in myGV.Rows)
{
    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        dataRow[myGV.Columns[i].HeaderText] = row.Cells[i].Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with the data object you're binding to the GridView, not the gridview.  There is no hook to the data in the gridview after binding.

Comment: +1 @William: additional note: if paging is(or will be) enabled, the DataTable's Rows would contain only the PageSize-number of DataRows that are currently visible. Hence the recommended way is to load the data from database again when you want to export it to CSV.

Comment: Ok thank you. My data source (a list of objects) has extra fields I don't need and the GridView OnDataBound event manipulates the data some. If I re-bind the GridView on postback can I access some sort of internal DataTable in the GridView to make my spreadsheet from? I guess my other option is to make a method that returns a data table and then use that for both my spreadsheet and GridView.